# Check values in DataTable

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

I have a `DataTable` dtOne, having records as below:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1001    W101    ARCH
1001    W102    ARCH
1002    W103    CUSS
1003    W104    ARCH
```

And another `DataTable` dtTwo, having values as:

```
ColumnA
ARCH
CUSS
```

I need to check whether values of dtTwo exist in dtOne or not, if not write it on the webpage.

I wrote the below code, but it doesn't work properly. I need to check like, if `ARCH` from dtTwo table is present in dtOne, don't check further, just write it to the webpage.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < dtTwo.Rows.Count; counter++)
   {
    var contains=dtOne.Select("ColumnC= '" + dtTwo.Rows[counter][0].ToString() + "'");
    if (contains.Length == 0)
      {
       Response.Write("CostCode "+dtTwo.Rows[counter][0].ToString()+" not present in the Excel");
      }
   }
```

Experts please help.

EDIT:
My functionality is achieved when I write the below code, but get a warning that unreachable code detected at counter variable.

I don't think its correct.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < dtTwo.Rows.Count; counter++)
       {
        var contains=dtOne.Select("ColumnC= '" + dtTwo.Rows[counter][0].ToString() + "'");
        if (contains.Length == 0)
          {
           Response.Write("CostCode "+dtTwo.Rows[counter][0].ToString()+" not present in the Excel");
          }
          break;
       }
```

Regards

Comment: [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) is your friend here.

Comment: Should it be added after the Response.Write line??

Comment: Yes, the for loop is interrupted at the break

Comment: Just to understand better. You want to stop writing in the Response after the first missing value. Right?

Comment: But wouldn't the for loop run for the consecutive iteration?

Comment: @Steve..a very simple thing. If Arch is present in the first datatable, just stop further checking and write to the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68592/discussion-between-anurag-and-steve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your clarification, you want to stop if you find a match from the second table in the first table.

Then you need to add the break statement when your Select finds one or more rows that matches the condition

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < dtTwo.Rows.Count; counter++)
{
    var contains=dtOne.Select("ColumnC= '" + dtTwo.Rows[counter][0].ToString() + "'");
    if (contains.Length != 0)
    {
       Response.Write("CostCode "+dtTwo.Rows[counter][0].ToString()+" not present in the Excel");
       break;
    }
}
```

From the C# reference

> The break statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch
>   statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that
>   follows the terminated statement, if any.

Comment: Mr.Steve..please have a look at my question again.. I have edited it.

Comment: As I have said in chat, you need that break inside the if{true-block} not after. If you put it after you exit from the for loop after the first iteration and the counter++ is never reached as you can see from the warning reveived